# Inheritance with dataclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, abstraction, python-dataclasses

I am trying to understand what are the good practices when using inheritance with dataclasses.
Let's say I want an "abstract" parent class containing a set of variables and methods, and then a series of child classes that inherit these methods and the variables, where in each of them the variables have a different default value.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class ParentClass:
    a_variable: str

    def a_function(self) -> None:
        print("I am a class")

# ONE
@dataclass
class DataclassChild1(ParentClass):
    a_variable: str = "DataclassChild"

# TWO
@dataclass
class DataclassChild2(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(a_variable="Child")

# THREE
class ClassChild(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(a_variable="Child")
```

What would be the correct way to implement this (one/two/three), if any? Or is it an overkill and it would be best to just use different instances of ParentClass, passing different values to the constructor?

I think I should use the `@dataclass` decorator also for the child classes, but if I check the type of the child class, that seems to be a dataclass even if I don't use it.

Plus, I feel like overwriting `__init__` defeats the purpose of using a dataclass in the first place, but on the other hand the standard dataclass syntax seems useless because it would mean having to rewrite all the variables in the child classes (`a_variable: str = "DataclassChild"`).

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a job for subclasses. It might be a job for a factory function, or for just using `ParentClass` directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "the standard dataclass syntax seems useless because it would mean having to rewrite all the variables in the child classes"? Dataclasses preserve their defaults down the hierarchy as far as I know.

Comment: You're right that defining `__init__` is worse than pointless, since it prevents the default implementation from being generated. If you illustrate the problem with doing it the other way, I could probably answer your question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What I meant by "the standard dataclass syntax seems useless" is that, in this case, there are no defaults in the parent class, so in each child class I would have to rewrite all the lines that define the variables, which I think defeats the original purpose
The only difference between 2 and 3 is that 2 had the dataclass decorator: this does not seem to change anything, which is a bit confusing to me

Comment: I'm not sure how that makes dataclasses more pointless than any other mechanism used to change a default value.

Comment: There's also a distinct difference between the examples. In 2 and 3, `a_variable` is not a dataclass field or init param anymore. In 1, user can still pass it into the constructor to set it to another value, for ex. like `DataclassChild1(a_variable='tst')`.

Comment: Beware of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violations: an instance of a subclass that *must* have a particular attribute value cannot in general be used in a context where the attribute value can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that #1 is the most correct method. For the example you showed, it appears to be irrelevant which method you use, but if you add a second variable, the differences become apparent. This is implicitly confirmed by the [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#inheritance) section in the documentation.

```
@dataclass
class ParentClass:
    a: str
    b: str = "parent-b"

# This works smoothly
@dataclass
class ChildClass1(ParentClass):
    a: str = "child-a"

# This works, but is a maintenance nightmare
@dataclass
class ChildClass2(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, a="child-a", b="parent-b"):
        super().__init__(a, b)

# This works, but it changes the signature and only works if a is first
@dataclass
class ChildClass3(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, a="child-a", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, **kwargs)
```

Right now, the [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) decorator is adding default methods, including `__init__` to your class. That means that if you wanted to use option #2 or #3, you would have to know and copy the function signature for *all* the parameters. At the same time, option #1 allows you to change the default for just `a`.

The other way to do what you're doing is to create a [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) method for your child classes, which can then override the parent default value:

```
@dataclass
class ParentClass:
    a: str = ''  # Or pick some other universally acceptable marker

@dataclass
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.a == '':
            self.a = "child-a"
```

This is also needlessly complex for most scenarios, but may be useful for a more complex situation. Normally `__post_init__` is meant to be used to initialize derived fields, as in the example in the linked documentation.